# Can I make the frame of my UIView match its great grandparent?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, bounds

I get frame/bounds at the simple level. Still trying to move up to a more advanced use...

I have a view stack that looks something like:

[image]

The `UICollectionViewCell` is actually my own subclass. I've set it's `selectionBackgroundView` as a stock `UIView`, and I toggle the `hidden` property at selection time. That container view contains one or more of my own `MyAnnotationView` instances. His purpose is to annotate the cell. But most of the drawing he does is actually around the `bounds` of the cell view.

For the cell, which may be at arbitrary positions in the `UICollectionView`, his `frame` and `bounds` will differ in the normal way (relative to parent and local respectively). In the case of the `UIView` and its subviews (MyAnnotationView instances), their frame and bounds will be the same, since they're coincident with each other.

But for the MyAnnotationView to do its drawing around the cell he's annotating, he needs to be aware of the cells frame. IOW, I want it's 0,0 point to be the same as the cell's, but I'd like it if I could refer to his frame, and have it be the same value as the cell's. Is that possible to configure the frame/bounds of that view that way? Or do I have to do a hardcoded search, e.g.

```
self.superview.superview.frame
```

The red line is a simple example of something I could do if I new the frame of the annotation view. I would path a line from the left middle of the annotation's bounds to the frame's left x negated, and same y value.

Maybe a more general version of this question would be, is there an (easy) way to sync the drawing the coordinate system of the annotation view with that of the UICollectionView, but still have it be aware of where the box it's annotating around, is at?

Comment: What are you attempting to draw in the annotation? Why do you need to know the position in the hierarchy above? Why are the local bounds not sufficient?

Comment: I draw connections to the edges some times. Also, there's some peer connections that get drawn, and those can be figured once the frame is known.

Comment: But can't you draw them locally? Could you perhaps add an illustration of such an annotation to your question?

Comment: I agree with Leo. If there's information the outside view needs to draw appropriately, it should be *told* that information. A view should never have any knowledge of other views outside of it. If you need to calculate specific coordinates, angles, etc., the cell can do the calculations.

Comment: @TravisGriggs As per your example, you should not be drawing the red line from inside a subview or even the cell.

Comment: @LeoNatan: Why? Drawing outside of the bounds of the view isn't bad, otherwise we wouldn't have a `clipsToBounds` property that defaults to `NO`. I admit, I may be going the wrong route here, my hands seem a little tied by `UICollectionView`. But maybe, I really need to pop back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386440/design-for-annotating-uicollectionview-selections-with-additional-controls. This question arose out of my choice to use option #2 shown there.

Comment: Whether this is a good idea or not, I'm still curious if it's doable.

Comment: @TravisGriggs OK, I'll type an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even though its late, for other people, here is a solution.
Override the applyLayoutAttributes from the parent class which is UICollectionViewCell or UICollectionReusableView

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    UIView *_annotationView;
}
@end

@implementation MyCustomCell
- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    _annotationView.frame = layoutAttributes.frame;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, ignoring bad design for a minute, the best method I would suggest for having the annotation views be aware of their position in the `UICollectionView` world is by passing keeping a weak reference to the collection view, and then querying that collection view in `layoutSubviews`.

So:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UICollectionView* owningCollectionView;
```

and

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.frameInCollectionViewSpace = [self.owningCollectionView convertRect:self.frame fromView:self];

    //Use it here
}
```